# How to get model instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a simple Rails application I'm using to try and learn Rails.

It has a database table I create like this using ActiveRecord:

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :movies do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :rating
      t.text :description
      t.datetime :release_date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :movies
  end
end
```

Here is my corresponding model class:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all_ratings
    %w(G PG PG-13 NC-17 R)
  end

  def name_with_rating()
    return "#{@title} (#{@rating})"
  end
end
```

When I call name_with_rating on an instance of Movie, all it returns is " ()" for any Movie.  What is the correct syntax or method to call to get at the fields of the Movie instance from within an instance method of Movie?

Please note that the database has been properly populated with movie rows, etc.  I've done rake db:create, rake db:migrate etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active record attributes aren't implemented as instance variables. Try

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name_with_rating()
    return "#{title} (#{rating})"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name_with_rating
     "#{title} (#{rating})"
  end
end
```

then in the console `Movie.first.name_with_rating` should work.